# terraform source_resource_id output

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

What is the syntax to assign the managed disk id from a newly created virtual machine to an output? I would like to use it as the "source_resource_id" of an "azurerm_managed_disk" resource.

I have tried the following within outputs.tf:

```
output "manageddisk" {
    value = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.storage_os_disk.[0].managed_disk_id
}
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid attribute name
│ 
│ On outputs.tf line 17: An attribute name is required after a dot.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all arguments can be used as attributes as they're two separate things. Terraform's docs distinguish this by having an "Argument Reference" and an "Attributes Reference" section for a given resource; only the attributes of a resource can be accessed.

One pathway is to create an [`azurerm_managed_disk`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/managed_disk) resource separately, which [does output](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/managed_disk#attributes-reference) the identifier of the managed disk. You can then use the managed disk's resource's `id` output as an input to the virtual machine you're provisioning:

```
output "manageddisk" {
    value = azurerm_managed_disk.example.id
}
```

From here you have the output of the managed disk, so you can use it for whatever you'd like.